# Objective-C. Class conforming to a protocols of an UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I have this Custom subclass of `UIViewController` where I've built an `UICollectionView`.

I am conforming to a `CollectionViewDelegates` and `CollectionViewDataSource` in that `UIViewController`.

Then Xcode asks me to put all the stubs that are needed. There is a lot of stubs. When I worked with Swift, I've added few stubs that I needed like `numbersOfItemsInSection` or `didSelectRowAt`. Now I've got over 10. To be completely honest, at this stage I would not even know what is the functionality of most of them. I will figure that out, but my main question is, do I need to use all of them? Or can I just delete them and forget about them right now? Some of them are:

```
didUpdateFocusInContext
viewWillTransitionToSize
systemLayoutFittingSizeDidChangeForChildContentContainer
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the delegate name in the .h file and jump to the definition. You require all methods not explicitly marked as @optional
I didn't check it for your example but here is a generic one

```
@protocol MyProtocol

- (void)requiredMethod;

@optional
- (void)anOptionalMethod;
- (void)anotherOptionalMethod;

@required
- (void)anotherRequiredMethod;

@end
```

Comment: Now I can see, that when Xcode is asking about adding stubs, it adds optional ones too. Then I can easily remove optional ones and it's all good. Thank You!